# Testing if an NSRunningApplication UI is idle

Tags: macos, user-interface, cocoa, applescript, appleevents

Outside of the context of a UI Unit Test, is there a way for a third-party application to see if an a particular running application on the system is busy processing events, or beach-balling, or is ready for a next event? Either by polling or with a callback/notification?

I'm scripting an uncooperative program with UI scripting but some of the things I do take a long time and right now I have to set a manual delay between events, which isn't optimal.